# Loop a ThreadGroup with parameters

Tags: jmeter

I'd like to stress test an REStful API with JMeter with different parameterization and capture the response time depending on the number of users and parameters used for the REST call:

```
             | 10 User | 100 Users | 1000 Users 
Parameters A |‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
Parameters B |‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
Parameters C |‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

So my HTTP Request is always the same, except for the Parameters and the number of users. My current (poor) approach is a thread group with a hardcoded number of threads for each combination of users and parameters. But i assume there is better approach available, with utilizing of variables.

Any suggestions on a clean implementation?

*Edit:* Basically i'm trying to achieve the following nested `for loops`.

```
for (param in parameters) {
    for (numReq in users) {
        executeRequest(param, numReq)
        // execute *numReq* simultaneous requests with the parameters of param
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JMeter Thread Groups are initialized during JMeter startup so unfortunately you won't be able to use [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) as they're being read and applied a little bit after.

However you can go for JMeter Properties instead. For instance, you can define number of users using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like :

```
${__P(threads,)}
```

and then you will be able to define threads number via `-J` command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jthreads=100 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of working with them.

If you're using [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) you can also consider trying out i.e. [Stepping Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/) instead

Comment: I think i failed to point out my problem precisely, reading /using properties isn't the problem. Please see my edit to the question for my struggle.

Comment: You can add parameters to the HTTP Request dynamically using i.e. [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) and [sampler.addArgument()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#addArgument(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method. See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide to learn how to use JMeter and Java API from Beanshell test elements